# Foo table Page limit of showing Page number not working

Tags: javascript, footable

I am using this code Page Size is working fine but Page limit is not working

```
<table class="footable table table-stripped toggle-arrow-tiny" data-paging="true"  data-page-navigation=".pagination" data-paging-limit="100" data-page-size=@ViewBag.PageSize   id="dtTable">
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to show 2 Page footer pagination button

Comment: That's not a question, you're just stating what you want, and "_not working_" doesn't describe the actual problem ... Please explain __in details__ what you want your code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: I want Page button dynamics by passing the page count in data-paging-limit="100"

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162017/how-to-limit-the-page-numbers-displayed-in-the-table-footer-in-footable
I cannot comment so I'm posting as answer.